# Run .EXE from asp.net 4.0, this exe will generate .CSV file, but exe is crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, iis, exe

Step 1.I have a web application, using which i am preparing .txt files(raw data files).
Step 2. After these files are created, i am using process and trying to execute a customized .exe file. This EXE will generate .CSV file based on the text files located in the path provided to process.
Step 3. This .EXE is initially starting but after few seconds it is crashing.
Step 4. When i am seeing the windows Event log, i am able to see the crash report. PFA the crash report.

Note: when i run all of this in Visual studio in dev pc, it is working fine, but when i am hosting, it is giving error.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.[Crash report from windows Event log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koi0J.png)

Comment: You're getting a simple Access Denied error. Try researching the actual error and find the required permissions. Google [has about 2000 hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=0xc0000005+iis+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the security policy of IIS. Had several applications, which needed to call an Application. After spending hours with editing Security settings and testing, I've ended up to outsource such Processes into WindowsServices.

The advantages are that it's more reliable and no high permissions for the web-app are needed.

To develop an easy and reliable solution you can use Windows Service + SignalR (SelfHost). But don't forget to restrict the access to the SignalR Server (only  allow traffic over the used port for your Webserver)